# Disable dashboard drag&drop

Tags: theme-development, widgets, dashboard

I need to disable drag&drop functionality for dashboard widgets.

This should be realized with jquery, just as it is for the dashboard_browser_nag. I'm no jquery expert - so can anybody tell me how to find and modify my widgets with jquery?

So far, I know that I have to do some .sortable("cancel"), but how exactly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will remove the draggable functionality from each widget:

```
jQuery('.widget.ui-draggable').draggable('destroy')
```

You have find a good way to inject this into your code, either through `wp_enqueue_script()` or echo it inline on the Widget page.

To target a specific Widget you would have to do something along these lines:

```
jQuery('.widget.ui-draggable').each(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).find('h4').text() == 'Archives')
        jQuery(this).draggable('destroy');
}
```

Or select your way around to find the widget by `id`:

```
widget-2_calendar-__i__
widget-3_categories-__i__
...
```

If you browse around the source you'll soon find out how these are internally formed by WordPress. The rest is up to jQuery, selectors, maybe regular expressions (though I don't recommend them in this case).

Comment: This is closer to my initial question. It works partially: I can still drag the widget around, but I can't drop it anymore. Results in some weird behaviour. :)
  
How can I prevent dragging as well?

Comment: You're doing it wrong, then. I've tested this out of context (through Firebug or whatever you use) and it blocked the dragging. Are you placing this in a `.ready()` context?

Comment: I can understand the php part of wordpress down to its internals quite well - but I have no experience with jquery. Maybe I should have stated this in a clearer way. :)  
  
I placed your code in a `.ready()` context now - looks like it is working. Just out of curiosity, this brings me to my initial question: how can I find specific widgets, and disable drag&drop only for them?

Comment: Added the reply to my answer. Please consider using Firebug/Chrome Developer Tools/etc. to find out how you can target individual widgets and check the [jQuery selector cheatsheet](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) on how to better get to them. Please limit further questions to WordPress (general jQuery questions do not belong here) or we're at risk of being closed :) Hope this helps.

Comment: Good going @Soulseekah! I was struggling with something similar when dealing with feature pointers in 3.3 :)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but this would atleast get you started. Add this to functions.php or make your own plugin for it.

```
function remove_drag_and_drop() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-ui-sortable' );
}
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'remove_drag_and_drop' );
```

Comment: that will break the menus page.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting approach. Isn't working like that however. My best so far is to prevent adding *any* footer scripts:

```
 function remove_footer_scripts() { return false; }
 add_filter('print_footer_scripts', 'remove_footer_scripts');
```

Clearly not a good solution. But the suggested `wp_dequeue_script` function to remove a single script is not working - maybe 'wp_dashboard_setup' is the wrong hook? I also tried to hook into 'wp_default_scripts' and to modify `$wp_scripts` itself, but without any success...

@Ijaas: good point, it would also break admin_widgets and admin_gallery, but isn't it possible to add the action/filter depending on the `$current_screen`? Should be, as it is a footer script which is added after `set_current_screen()` was called.

Comment: You can use a built-in `__return_false` function too, but as you said, this is not the best approach.